# Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c cat <stuff I wanna see>") always returns null

Tags: java, android, su

I'm trying to read values for hardware usage statistics from an Android app, and a few of the files need root access to read.  I've tried running the following code in the app, but its always returning null.  On the terminal I'm using, I get the results I am expecting with the same command.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c cat <stuff I wanna see>");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        val  = line.split("[ ]+");
```

Anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c \" cat <Stuff you want>\"");
```